# Add in app purchase product image screenshot using rest api

Tags: rest, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add the in app purchase product using the Rest API, but when i am trying to upload the screenshot using v1/inAppPurchaseAppStoreReviewScreenshots using this api i am getting 500 server error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuEyI.png)

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.